# How to publish database to Azure using Visual Studio Code on Mac?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, visual-studio-code, entity-framework-core

I built asp.net MVC Core web app using Visual Studio Code on Mac. The app is working with database (EF) in localhost all along.

I have an Azure account with Web App + SQL Database created. Then I have changed the connection string in `appsetting.json` to that provided by Azure SQL Database.

The website is deployed to Azure Web App using `git push azure master` command. But how to publish the database to Azure?

---

In `appsetting.json` :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"AzureConnection": "Server=tcp:myapp-test.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=myapp-test;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=***;Password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
}
```

Output after I run `dotnet ef database update` :

```
bash-3.2$ dotnet ef database update
Project MyApp (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because project is not safe for incremental compilation. Use --build-profile flag for more information.
Compiling BlueJacket for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
Bundling with configuration from /Users/matt/Documents/MyApp/bundleconfig.json
Processing wwwroot/css/site.min.css
Processing wwwroot/js/site.min.js
Compilation succeeded.
0 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)
Time elapsed 00:00:05.1136780
(The compilation time can be improved. Run "dotnet build --build-profile" for more information)
Done.
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you created a database in Azure yet?  Do you have a connection string?

Open Package-Manager and run "Update-Database"

Comment: Yes I have created a database and add the connection string to `appsetting.json` already.

Comment: I use command `dotnet ef database update` but still doesn't work?

Comment: What does it say?  you can add verbose

Comment: I put the output and connection string on the post. Can you have a look please?

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with doing this from a Mac..  I'd expect to see it attempt to update the db.   What does your Database context class look like?

Comment: I had a chance to connect Azure SQL Database with SQL Server Management Studio and found out the database is well published. The problem now is when I go to my Azure URL, only "An error occurred while starting the application." is shown without any details. Would it be possible that the free trial version limits it's ability to work with DB?